# Kotlin test if a float is in open or semi-open range

Tags: kotlin, range

In Kotlin, is there an idiomatic way to test if a float is in a range where either (or both) the start or the end of the range is exclusive?

E.g. something like

```kotlin
val inRange = 10.f in (0.0f until 20f)
```

I can't seem to find anything on this in the docs.

How would one deal with semi-open ranges as well?

Comment: Bear in mind that floating-point numbers are inherently imprecise.  (In decimal terms, anyway: just as there's no terminating decimal fraction for 1/3, so there's no terminating binary fraction for 1/10.  So you can't represent 0.1 exactly in a binary floating-point value.)  So you really don't want to be relying on exactly whether a range includes its endpoint, as your value may have wandered quite a bit due to all the binary approximations!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `until` function creates the semi-closed integer (not float) range, where the left part is included and the right part is excluded.
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/ranges.html

There is closed float ranges support in Koltin
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/ranges.html#utility-functions

You may implement that yourself

```
data class OpenFloatRange(val from: Float, val to: Float)
infix fun Float.open(to: Float) = OpenFloatRange(this, to)
operator fun OpenFloatRange.contains(f: Float) = from < f && f < to

val inRange = 10f in (0.0f open 20f)
```

Here I use several tricks from Kotlin:
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#infix-notation
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/operator-overloading.html#in

Comment: I find this answer beautiful :) out of curiosity, any reason why you didn't name the extension `until`?

Comment: This is a nice solution for a open float range! But how would one easily deal with semi-open float ranges? One could possibly create separate classes for all alternatives (open-open, open-closed, closed-open, closed-closed), but it would'nt be that pretty!

Comment: @MariusKohmann You could just have two extra properties: `isLeftClosed: Boolean, isRightClosed: Boolean`.

Answer (score 3):

Inspired by what i selected as answer i came up with this solution, posting it here if anyone wants to reuse it.

```
class Range(private val fromInclusive: Boolean, val from: Float, val to: Float, private val toInclusive: Boolean) {

    infix fun contains(value: Float): Boolean {
        return when {
            fromInclusive && toInclusive -> value in from..to
            !fromInclusive && !toInclusive -> value > from && value < to
            !fromInclusive && toInclusive -> value > from && value <= to
            fromInclusive && !toInclusive -> value >= from && value < to
            else -> false
        }
    }
}
```

Usage: `val inRange = Range(true, 0f, 10f, false) contains 5f`

Answer (score 2):

There is a new end-enclusive operator **`..<`** (called rangeUntil) which is still experimental and can be enabled in Kotlin **`1.7.20`** and newer.

Add the following in *build.gradle.kts* (Kotlin `1.8` and newer does not need this):

```kotlin
kotlin {
    jvm {
        compilations.all {
            kotlinOptions.languageVersion = "1.8" // Treat Kotlin code as version 1.8
            // ...
        }
```

It opens possibilities that could not be done with `until`:

```kotlin
val floatRange = 0f ..< 10f
val dateRange = LocalDate.of(2022, 1, 1) ..< LocalDate.of(2023, 1, 1)
val stringRange = "1z" ..< "9a"
// OR anything implementing Comparable

when (7.89f) {
    in floatRange -> println("Number is in range")
    else -> println("Number is NOT in range")
}
```

##### NOTE: Remember to add `@OptIn(ExperimentalStdlibApi::class)` to your functions where you use this operator

See [official Kotlin video introducing the `rangeUntil` operator](https://youtu.be/v0AHdAIBnbs).